# Correctly scanning a blank input with the Scanner object

Tags: java

I'm working on creating a basic guitar inventory and I'm doing testing with scanner, I was trying to scan a blank entry and when there is a blank entry it should print "ANY" and it does, i'm using scan.useDelimiter("\z");  and now when I enter a correct entry like "fender" it should print "FENDER" but it just prints "ANY" as if the entry was incorrect.. someone know what I can do to solve that problem? Here is an sscce:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SSCCE {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a builder name: ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        scan.useDelimiter("\\z"); // count a blank entry (end of input)


        String entry_1 = scan.next();


        if (entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("FENDER")
                        || entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("MARTIN")
                        || entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("GIBSON")
                        || entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("COLLINGS")
                        || entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("OLSON")
                        || entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("RYAN") 
                        || entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("PRS")) 
        {
            entry_1 = entry_1.toUpperCase();

            System.out.println(entry_1);
        }

        else
        {       
            entry_1 = "ANY";

            System.out.println(entry_1);
        }   
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the scanner removes the delimiter from the tokens it return.  When the delimiter was a line break (the default), when you do fender, entry_1 was assigned "fender".  After you changed the delimiter, the line break caused by the enter is no longer removed, so you get "fender\n" in entry_1, causing your if condition to fail.

To fix, just do String entry_1 = scan.next().trim(); instead which removes the trailing linebreak.

Comment: Ah I knew there would be a workaround, thanks. I knew that a new line was appending to whatever I entered, and I was trying many things like  if(entry_1.equalsIgnoreCase("FENDER" + "\r\n"), and wasn't working but the trim function gets it to work. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can try printing the scanned value to see why it is not going into the if statement.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SSCCE {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Enter a builder name: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    scan.useDelimiter("\\z"); // count a blank entry (end of input)


    String entry_1 = scan.next();

    System.out.println("Input = [" + entry_1 + "]");

    // rest of the code...
}
```

Comment: If you do this suggestion I'm guessing you find that it is scanning more than you want it to due to \z delimiter. You probably only want to scan one line instead of the whole System.in stream.

Comment: I think he is scanning only one name at a time, though. If not, then your point is absolutely correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to your use of `\\z`. Look at this [regex tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) for a more detailed story. For solving your problem, suffice it to say that changing it to `\\Z` should do the trick. The following code is working for me:

```
public static final Set<String> names = Sets.newHashSet("martin", "gibson", ...);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter a builder name: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    scan.useDelimiter("\\Z"); // count a blank entry (end of input)

    String entry = scan.next();
    entry = "any" if (!names.contains(entry.toLowerCase());
    System.out.println(entry.toUpperCase());
}
```

Note: I assumed you are scanning one name at a time. If not, then just use line break.